# The Point of Using apply_filters()

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

While i'm Trying To Develop a plugin, i tried to See some other plugin do the same stuff my plugin will achieve, then i saw The developer in the most functions work with the function `apply_filters()` and i didn't understand why .
This is an Example Below :

```
public static function myFunction() {
    return apply_filters( 'du/class/method' array(
        'index'    => 'value',
        'index'    => 'value',
        'index'    => 'value',
        'index'    => 'value',
    ) );
}
```

as you Can See in the first parameter in the function `apply_filters()` there is a string parameter, everywhere i see this function always i see something like `du/class/method` .

Please is There Any Explanation For That .

Comment: Have you looked at the Codex for how apply_filters works? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/ . Or searched here for many similar questions? Or asked the googles, which might have directed you to other tutorials about this (like https://wpshout.com/apply_filters-do_action/ )?

Comment: @RickHellewell Yes i did all the things you Advices me to do, but unfortunately i didn't understand right what's the point of using it, can you Please Explain to Me Quickly, maybe your answer will be understandable .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to allow developers to customise aspects of your theme or plugin.

When calling `apply_filters()` you provide a name and a value that you want developers to be able to filter.

For your example:

```
$array = apply_filters( 'du/class/method' array(
    'index'    => 'value',
    'index'    => 'value',
    'index'    => 'value',
    'index'    => 'value',
) );
```

Developers can now change the value of `$array` in your plugin by using the `du/class/method` filter with `add_filter()`. To add an item, perhaps:

```
function wpse_303378_filter( $array ) {
    $array[] = 'New item';

    return $array;
}
add_filter( 'du/class/method', 'wpse_303378_filter' );
```

The name of the filter, in this case `du/class/method` can be whatever you want it to be, but many developers will 'namespace' it so it doesn't conflict with any other plugins. Advanced Custom Fields, for example, prefixes all its hooks with `acf/`. Your example implies that the filter name uses the class and method that it occurs in as a way to group related filters, but it will depend on the plugin.

You can read more about filters [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/).

Comment: I don't Know How to Thank you, now i understand it Very well, so Thank you very Much